# how to work with Vagrant with github repository?

Tags: php, github, vagrant

Someone please describe how to work with vagrant? what i have done so far

I have installed Virtual Machine
Installed Vagrant
run few command and now Ubuntu 32 bit is installed in virtual machine

[image: see virtual machine]
I have my project on github.
I make clone of the repository on my desktop ( D:)
created clone on my desktop

now my question is how to work with this repository code and associate vagrant?

Clearly no idea what this Vagrant actually is?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have web project written in php. First you need to define vagrant folder. Clone your repository to the folder from your host machine. For folder in guest machine , let apache  know where is you host. This is the step you need to do. 
But I wanna suggest you to learn how vagrant work first. If you don't know the concept, it will not be ok. And you can use https://puphpet.com/ for vagrant configuration.